# Yajra Datatables with postgreSQL

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

I am using [yajra datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/) in Laravel for a while but I have a problem with search on postgreSQL.

Every time I want to search something I get

```
SQLSTATE[42601]:Syntax error:7 ERROR zero-length delimited identifier at or near """" LINE 1: name as TEXT))...
```

I suppose that is because different search query on postgreSQL but don't know where to change that and how to setup correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what cause a problem. It's not a package problem with postgreSQL but with eloquent relations that Model::query in datatables don't recognize and can't search. I must edit column where I have a relation data and return it back